# Avoid start an activity from itself

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a custom button bar in my app that i use it in several activity.
It have a settings button that start `SettingsActivity`.

**Problem is:**

that i use this button bar in `SettingsActivity` too and i want to avoid start `SettingsActivity` from itself. 
I set onClick for button in a fragment and i use this fragment in my activities then i cant set any flag or extra data.

in onClick of Setting button i set the intent like this :

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**What i do :**

I have `ParentActivity` that all other activity extend from it and i override `startActivityForResult` method in it.
the result is that i have the intent that start `SettingsActivity`.

```
@Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
    }
```

**What i want:**

I want to know how can i detect which activity called this intent and which activity will be start ?

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: You can only detect which activity started another activity if you manually include that information as part of the intent. For example you could add the classname of the calling activity as an intent extra.

I am not sure why you override startActivityForResult? Perhaps you should elaborate your usecase some more.

Comment: However, I doubt this is what you really want to do. The description is not quite clear, but to me it sounds like you're trying to create a component that can be reused across different activities. It sounds like it might be a better idea to implement this as a fragment?

Comment: @y.feizi you can add flags while sending the Intents.

Comment: the problem is that i use a single method for all of activities

Comment: I edited my question , i hope its more clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload startActivityForResult with another parameter `name`. So in the onClick of the Settings button, you simply use the overloaded method:

```
onClick(View v){
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1, this.getClass().getName());
}
```

ParentActivity:

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, String name) {
if(!name.equals(com.yourpackage.settingsactivity))
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
else Toast.makeText(this, "Already in SettingsActitivty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
}
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming all you need to do is to avoid calling SettingsActivity from itself, I recommend you try one of the built-in launch modes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

If you use `singleTop` for your SettingsActivity, starting it when it's already at the top of your stack will NOT cause a new activity to be started, but rather the existing activity will get its `onNewIntent()` method called (which you can ignore if you don't need to take any action).

Alternatively, if for some reason this wouldn't work, taking Marlon's suggestion one step further, and assuming you start the `SettingsActivity` with an explicit intent (setting the class name), you could override `startActivityForResult` and check if the calling activity is the same as the target activity, without having to overload the method with a `name` parameter.

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    if (!intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals(getClass().getName()) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}
```